# Least Squares Approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Given:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
-2 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}$

How do I find the least squares approximation and compute the error.

I understand I should use:

$\hat{x} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$

Where $y = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}$

However, looking at $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
-2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$ and applying to $(A^TA)^{-1}$ I dont understand how to finish the projection because it doesnt have an inverse.

Could someone maybe explain it step-by-step so I can wrap my head around it? I understand that I am trying to find the vector that is on the plane closest to the vector not on the plane, but how do I compute the error for it? Isint least squares already the smallest error?

Thanks

Comment: Since $A$ is singular, there will be infinitely many vectors $\mathbf{x}=[x\ y]^T$ that minimize $\|\mathbf{x} - [1\ 5]^T\|$ (sorry, I forgot how to typeset vectors/matrices).  They will satisfy $A^T A \mathbf{x} = A^T [1\ 5]^T$. I think the standard "best" answer is the vector of minimum norm minimizing $\|\mathbf{x} - [1\ 5]^T\|$.  The "Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse" may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a general case and then explain your case. I'm following the terminology in "Introduction to Linear Algebra (4th ed.)" by Gilbert Strang.

## General case

$A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ with $m\times n$ matrix $A$ does not have a solution $\mathbf{x}$ when $\mathbf{b}$ is not in $C(A)$ (column space of $A$, i.e., set of all vectors represented by a linear combination of $A$'s column vectors).

In that case, $\mathbf{b}$'s projection onto $C(A)$ would be the "best" approximation that minimizes the error. Let $\mathbf{p}$ denote the projection and $\mathbf{e}$ denote the error vector (= $\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p}$).

Because $\mathbf{p} \in C(A)$, there exists $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ that satisfies $A\mathbf{\hat{x}} = \mathbf{p}$. Also because $\mathbf{p}$ is a projection onto $C(A)$, $\mathbf{e} \perp C(A)$. In other words, $\mathbf{e}$ is perpendicular to all column vectors of $A$, so we have $A^T \mathbf{e} = \mathbf{0}$.

Using $\mathbf{e} = \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{\hat{x}} $, we have $A^T (\mathbf{b} - A\mathbf{\hat{x}}) = \mathbf{0}$, i.e., $A^TA\mathbf{\hat{x}} = A^T \mathbf{b}$.

### When $A^TA$ is invertible

You can solve it and get $\mathbf{\hat{x}} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T \mathbf{b}$ and also get the projection (i.e., least squares approximation) $\mathbf{p} = A\mathbf{\hat{x}} = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T \mathbf{b}$.

### When $A^TA$ is non-invertible

When $A^TA$ is non-invertible, there is no unique solution for $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$. Nullspace of $A^TA$ (denoted $N(A^TA)$; set of all vectors that satisfy $A^TA\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$) contains non-zero vectors $\mathbf{x_n}$. Let's call them "special solutions", following the Strang's book.

There also exists a "particular solution" $\mathbf{x_p}$ that satisfies $A^TA\mathbf{x_p} = A^T \mathbf{b}$. We can prove that such $\mathbf{x_p}$ always exists in the following way:

> To prove $\mathbf{x_p}$ exists, we need to show $A^T \mathbf{b} \in C(A^TA)$. It can be shown as follows:
>
> - $A^T\mathbf{b} \in C(A^T)$: Trivial
> - $A^T\mathbf{b} \perp N(A)$: Orthogonal complement; any vector perpendicular to $C(M)$ is in $N(M^T)$
> - $A^T\mathbf{b} \perp N(A^TA)$: $N(A) = N(A^TA)$, which is shown from $A^TA \mathbf{y} = 0 \Leftrightarrow A \mathbf{y} = 0$ for any $\mathbf{y}$
> - $A^T\mathbf{b} \in C(A^TA)$: Orthogonal complement and $(A^TA)^T = A^TA$

Then the solution for $\mathbf{\hat{x}} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T \mathbf{b}$ is $\mathbf{\hat{x}} = \mathbf{x_p} + c \mathbf{x_n}$ for any constant $c$. Note that the projection (i.e., least square approximation) is still unique, because we have $\mathbf{p} = A \mathbf{\hat{x}} = A \mathbf{x_p} + c A \mathbf{x_n} = A \mathbf{x_p}$. Notice $A\mathbf{x_n} = \mathbf{0}$ because $\mathbf{x_n} \in N(A^TA) = N(A)$.

## Your case

$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
-2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}$, then
$A^TA = 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -10\\ 
-10 & 20
\end{bmatrix}$, $A^T \mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}
-9 \\ 
18
\end{bmatrix}$

$A^TA$ is non-invertible and we can choose a special solution for $A^TA \mathbf{x_n} = \mathbf{0}$ as
$\mathbf{x_n} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

One particular solution $\mathbf{x_p}$ for $A^TA\mathbf{x_p} = A^T \mathbf{b}$ is
$\mathbf{x_p} = \begin{bmatrix}
-9/5 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Then $\mathbf{\hat{x}} = \mathbf{x_p} + c \mathbf{x_n} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-9/5 + 2c\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix}$
for any constant $c$.

Projection (i.e., least squares approximation) is
$\mathbf{p} = A \mathbf{\hat{x}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -10\\ 
-10 & 20
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
-9/5 + 2c\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
-9\\ 
18
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: When $A^TA$ is non-invertible, $A^+ \mathbf{b}$ (where $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$) is one of the solutions for $^\mathbf{\hat{x}} =^\mathbf{}$. See the end of Chapter 7.3 (p.404) in the Strang's book (4th ed.).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the inverse, solve $Mx=b$ using Gaussian elimination, where $M=(A^TA)$ and $b=A^Ty$.

Comment: Thats what I have been trying and I never get an answer. Do you mind explaining the steps?

Comment: And does that work every time? Thanks

Comment: Since your system is underdetermined, you will have not one solution but infinitely many.

Comment: Yeah, I know its undetermined because the vector is not on the plane and does not have a solution. Thats why I am trying to find the x,y that is the closest to the vector. Can you explain your steps on how you got your final answer? I have been trying to figure out your process with no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

step one: differentiate $(Ax-b)^2$ get $A^TAx=A^Tb$
          $\qquad$ This means for any x s.t. $A^TAx=A^Tb$, it will give you a maximum or minimum. Therefore there are three cases: 1. the result exists and is unique,  2. the result exists and is not unique,  3. the result does not exist. (Just solve two simutaneous equations.)

step two: Since $(Ax-b)^2$ can be any large, the result must be minimum.  The solution is: $x^*$=[-0.5556 1.1111].  Error =  $(Ax^*-b)^2$